# Magento 2 config CDN for specific file type only

Tags: magento2, requirejs, cdn

Magento 2 allow to add another url for static views file, but all static file types will be requested to this url.

[image]

I want to some only file types be served using that url. Example *.js and *.css files are served via CDN, and all other file type are served from my server. Is that possible?

If I get it right, `require.js` is using baseUrl on very beginning of each pages to resolve static url, so may be I can 'tweak' it?

Comment: You will need code change. Could be quite difficult.